# Proxies when using PyQt to render HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm looking to scrape JavaScript-driven pages using this code, which has appeared on a number of past threads (c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116946/pyqt5-for-web-scraping-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241872/how-to-download-from-javascript-rendered-webpage/35245162), and others on offsite threads):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

def render(source_html):
    class Render(QWebEngineView):
        def __init__(self, html):
            self.html = None
            self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
            self.setHtml(html)
            while self.html is None:
                self.app.processEvents(QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents | QEventLoop.ExcludeSocketNotifiers | QEventLoop.WaitForMoreEvents)
            self.app.quit()

        def _callable(self, data):
            self.html = data

        def _loadFinished(self, result):
            self.page().toHtml(self._callable)

    return Render(source_html).html
```

It's working fine.

My question is whether I need to use a proxy for this portion of the code (assuming that I generally want to be using a proxy for all network activity).

I'm using urllib.request and a proxy to access the site in question, and then passing the html from there on to PyQt5 to do the JavaScript mambo. Does that second leg of the journey involve a network connection that should be proxy-fied? If so, how should I change this code - haven't touched PyQt until today and am feeling a bit over my head.

Using Python 3.5 and Windows 7.

Many thanks.